# show default value in select input with backgroundcoulr different for each : react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have some select buttons displayed dynamicaly based on the `user.subscription` the values in `user.subscription`  can be 2 monthpack , 3 month pack, 6month pack, 12month pack,

so the value in  user.subscription` sould be selected as default when the maping loads in all

also  there must be differt colours for backgound of the slected button based on the default select button
button

if

2 month package is the default seleted then   `defaultcolor`  should be **red**

if

3  month package is the default seleted then   `defaultcolor`  should be **green**

if

6  month package is the default seleted then   `defaultcolor` should be **yellow**

if

12  month package is the default seleted then   `defaultcolor`  should be **orange**

```
{
  data.map((user) => (
    <select
      value={user.subscription}
      style={{ background: defaultcolor }}
      onChange={handleBackground}
    >
      <option value="white"> 2 month package</option>
      <option value="green">3 month package</option>
      <option value="red">6 month package</option>
      <option value="yellow">12 month package</option>
    </select>
  ));
}
```

Comment: please add sample code in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @A.R.SEIF   https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-resonance-hkbo4?file=/src/App.js   currently i have only one suscribe so there is only one entry

Comment: change function ```function handleBackground(e) {
    console.log("cfcvrr");
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setdefaultcolor(e.target.value);
  }```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-flower-gkxxm?file=/src/App.js:1347-1478

Comment: @A.R.SEIF thanks for the reply but this is not what iam looking for i want colours to load on default based on the value from api

Comment: here when the page initaily loads its white

Comment: what's default value function?

Comment: the value loaded from  user.subscription

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240250/discussion-between-a-r-seif-and-meon).

Comment: @A.R.SEIF did u find any aswers sir??

Comment: Hello .Not yet. I live in Iran and the weekend here is Friday.

Comment: hello sir could u pls help me out i need to finsh this today its important pls help sir

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-flower-gkxxm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: But I do not think the code is clean

Comment: @A.R.SEIF when i cahnge value in one select button everyvere else colour changes

Answer (score 0):

you can hold a small 'configuration' object like this:

```html
const monthToColor = {
  2: 'red',
  3: 'green',
  6: 'yellow',
  12: 'orange'
}
```

The keys should match the user.subscription options you have.

Now, for each option, add a style with background color of: monthToColor[user.subscription] like this:

```js
<option style={{ backgroundColor: monthToColor[user.subscription] }}>
  months
</options>
```